# Create Azure Management Site

Tags: azure

Can we create a sites that can:

- showing available VMs;
- deallocate VMs;
- show pings.

I prefer using Node, but other language is accepted.

Currently, I'm monitoring using azure-cli. But, I'm asked to create a more user friendly UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the operations that you can perform on the azure portal can be done using azure management api and powershell azure commandlets.

Azure management API are REST based and hence can be consumed from any platform that supports http.
Sample to start and stop VM - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-start-deallocated-c23b7cbe

Likewise you can write your own program to do the required management activities.

Comment: Do you have API documentation link? I don't really get with the Microsoft design flow, it's really hard to search something.

Comment: Ah, I also got that when I Google. I guess, it's just me confused with the "role" things. Thanks.

Comment: Good that it helped you.

Comment: Do you know how to get list of available machines? Currently I do static checking of each VMs.

Comment: You would need to get a list all the Cloud Services (Hosted Services), and then the deployment properties for each. Look for the deployment in the Production environment/slot. Then check for a role type of "PersistentVMRole". use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee460806.aspx

Comment: Hmm, Azure is complicated.

And, one more. Could I get <subs-id> using other ways instead of Active Directory? E.g. using .publishsettings file like Azure-cli do. I don't really understand Active Directory, and my senior using separate AD in separate VMs.

Comment: I am not sure why you would need an active directory in this case. getting subscription is straight forward.powershell is an easier way to get things done with azure IaaS. get all vms PS. http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/05/10/get-a-list-of-virtual-machines-by-using-powershell.aspx

Comment: Because it's what it says here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx.
Security at cost of simplicity, eh?

Comment: AD is one option to authenticate. You can always use the management certificate as you had done it for CLI. But for management purposes i feel powershell automation is the best option.

Comment: Now I'm searching how to invoke powershell commandlets on Linux/Node server.